# How to check if the AC laptop adapter is plugged or not?

Tags: bash, scripts, adapter

I need to check in a bash script running when my laptop starts if the AC adapter is plugged or not. Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`acpi`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/acpi/) with `-a` argument. To see how it works, run in your terminal:

```
acpi -a
```

By default, `acpi` package is not installed in Ubuntu, but is very easy and quickly to install from your terminal using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
```

Then, in your script you can use for example:

```
ac_adapter=$(acpi -a | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d- -f1)

if [ "$ac_adapter" = "on" ]; then
    notify-send "AC Adapter" "The AC Adapter is on."
else
    notify-send "AC Adapter" "The AC Adapter is off."
fi
```

To make the script to run at start up, just add a new entry in your crontab list (using `crontab -e` command) as follow:

```
@reboot DISPLAY=:0.0 /path/to/your/script
```

Comment: Nice answer, my next question would have been about battery state, but `acpi` solve this problem too. Thank you!